# Ember data api endpoint versus mapped route pluralization

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

Consider having a Dynamic routing page at `http://localhost:4200/organizer/{organizer-id}` which fetches data from a RESTful JSONAPI adapter.

organizer.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('organizer', params.organizer_id);
  }
});
```

Ember data pluralizes `organizer` into `organizers` when fetching data from the REST adapter. From the docs this seems to be the **intended** behavior, i.e. /organizers/{organizer-id}.

Yet, from their guide at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/defining-your-routes/, they seem to suggest this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
});
```

Isn't this a contradiction? How can these routes be singular while the api endpoint above is pluralized?

Comment: You're confusing route paths and API endpoints.

Comment: Fill me in please. For route paths, the convention is `/post/1`, while it is `/posts/1` for API endpoints?

Comment: All else being equal, yes, usually. For fun, try a model named `cow` and see what the API endpoint is.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the route paths and API endpoints. For the API endpoints not to rename the noun model (organizer) to use an adapter: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_pathForType

```
//app/adapters/organizer
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(){
    return "organizer";
  }
});
```

In regards to your example using the router mapping, these are the paths of the ember application you can reach via the url bar, not the underlying API calls.